# Tag canvas Plugin in IE 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using [TagCanvas Plugin](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php) and want to test it in IE 8 browser, as documented i added [Exoplorer canvas for IE <9](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) , i am unable to intialize the canvas element and view it in IE 8 !

```
     <head>
         <script src="excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="tagcanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            window.onload = function () {
                try {
                    TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas');
                } catch (e) {
                    // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
                    alert("cannot load");
                    document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
                }
            };
     </script>
        </head>
<body>
   <div id="myCanvasContainer">
 <canvas width="300" height="300" id="myCanvas">

  <ul>

   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>

  </ul>
 </canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

could i know if i am missing any reference for canvas element to be supported in IE 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

## See:

---

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a `JavaScript library that detects which HTML5 and CSS3 features` your visitor’s browser supports. In detecting feature support, `it allows developers to test for some of the new technologies and then provide fallbacks for browsers` that do not support them. This is called `feature detection and is much more efficient than browser sniffing.`

Using canvas as an example again, you’ll generally want a fallback for non-supporting IE8 and below. 
The usual way of doing this would be to link to a JavaScript polyfill, such as FlashCanvas in your HTML:

```
<script src="http://flashcanvas.net/bin/flashcanvas.js"></script>
```

`The problem with this approach is that all browsers will download this script.`
That’s unnecessary and `should be avoided where possible.`

You could arguably wrap the `<script>` element in conditional comments, but if you can keep the files out of the markup altogether, then you should. `You can do this using Modernizr.load().`

Modernizr `has YepNope built into it`, so you can easily test for a feature and then supply a polyfill.

The basic use of the `.load() function` allows you to `test` for a feature and `ask whether it’s true (yep) or false (nope).`
 In this example, `Modernizr tests for canvas support`, and `if the feature doesn’t exist, then it loads FlashCanvas`:

---

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.canvas,
  nope: 'http://flashcanvas.net/bin/flashcanvas.js'
});
```

---